# Add a new element to existing JSON array

Tags: sed, bash-scripting, perl

How can I add `"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/3"` line below `"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/2"` adding a comma after `"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/2"`,.

Before:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/1",
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/2"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

After

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/1",
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/2",
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/3"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not try to parse JSON text with standard text processing tools like `awk`, `sed` or without JSON modules in `perl`, as they are non JSON syntax aware. `jq` is a lightweight JSON processor that allows you manipulate content on the fly.

For e.g. your requirement could be simply written as

```
jq --arg new "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/3" \
  '.Statement[].Principal.AWS? += [$new]' json
```

If there is more than one element to be appended, create the arg as a JSON blob

```
jq --argjson new \
  '["arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/3", "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/4"]' \
  '.Statement[].Principal.AWS? += $new'
```

Instructions for downloading and using the tool are at [Download jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) and usage tutorial at [jq Manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)

If the contents are in a file and you want to modify this file permanently, use a in-place edit tool like `sponge` available from GNU moreutils package which you can do

```
jq --arg new "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/3" \
  '.Statement[].Principal.AWS? += [$new]' json | sponge json
```

or use a POSIX tool like `mktemp`

```
temp="$(mktemp)"
jq --arg new "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/3" \
  '.Statement[].Principal.AWS? += [$new]' json > "$temp" && mv "$temp" json
```

Comment: Genius, let me test this. I use jq a lot to read but never to add.

Comment: I used this and it worked aws iam get-role --role-name <rolename> | jq --arg new "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/3" '.Role.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS? += [$new]' > role.json

Comment: Thanks, I always found jq difficult to use but I'm getting better at it.

Comment: Do you know how can I add multiple entires one under another? Example: "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/3" "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/4"

Comment: @tr53: See update

Comment: Is there any way to add them one under another but not as array ?

Comment: ok, I've done it.

Comment: Why didn't you use redirection or `tee` to save the results permanently?